# Google Maps Navigation Icons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation, app-icons, icon-packs

I'm trying to get hold of the icons used in the step-by-step view of Google Maps

[image]

I've extracted the APK from my device and scoured through the drawables folders etc but cannot find them anywhere. They are also not listed on the [Material Design Icons webpage](https://material.io/icons/).

Does anyone know where they are stored?

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly what I was after, I have found a way I can get hold of them for now.

Stupidly, I didn't even think to have a play with desktop Maps. I followed the image URL for an icon when using directions on the desktop app which gave me a PNG with, what seems to be, all of the icons - [maneuvers-2x.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/tactile/directions/text_mode/maneuvers-2x.png)

May be of use to anyone else interested

Comment: Also available 4x version... : 
https://maps.gstatic.com/tactile/directions/text_mode/maneuvers-4x.png

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where they are stored but below are sources to obtain

[Google Navigation Icons](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/google_icons_navigation.asp) has  some them. See [material design navigation icons on GitHub](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/navigation)- perhaps this is what you are looking for

For other icons

[Google Earth/Maps Icons](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/icons.html) has

> a useful cheat sheet showing all the standard icons to use in Google Earth, Google Maps, and other map related applications. All icons are PNG images and include standard symbols for weather, highway, roads, numbers, arrows, etc.

**[Source: Google Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/LBTLwkERgoA)**

Comment: Unfortunately none of the links are what I'm looking for. The first two links relate to navigation in the context of app navigation - menu buttons, refersh buttons etc. The third link is (or at least looks) very old and I had already looked on here. They do not provide any of the icons in the screenshot I provided.

Comment: Interesting, but not answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this answers directly the question, but it can help. Actually, I think you asked two questions.

**1. How to get hold of the icons?**

The JavaScript API can get hold of the *maneuver icons* for specific directions. See the links below. I do not know if this will provide a straightforward access to each icon, but in the worst case you might get them by "brute force", by requesting directions that you know the icons they will get (perhaps one at a time).

a. [Google Directions API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941812/google-directions-api) question has very useful info.

b. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24325534/2707864) to [Google Maps v3 Direction Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561864/google-maps-v3-direction-icons) is probably the most useful.

c. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36959630/2707864) to [Get between streets in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958584/get-between-streets-in-google-maps).

d. [This](https://github.com/perezdidac/google-directions-api) is also interesting.

**2. Where are they stored?**

The location you are looking for is apparently not yet documented. 
See for instance [this](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4297&q=apitype=DirectionsAPI&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal).
One place to get them is [tt3.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/dir/tt3.png) (similar to what you found).